# Error: Could not find or load main class Spring Boot application

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application and I can't figure out why I am getting this "Error: Could not find or load main class com.example....".

I am only getting this problem with the jar file, packaged with maven, which is including all dependencies. The jar file without dependencies is working just fine, as the whole project in STS. I have read this question ([What does "Could not find or load main class" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean)) and all the linked articles and it still is above my head. I did everything suggested and in the end it still threw the same error. I do have now `Main-Class: com.fully.qualified.name` in my MANIFEST.MF in the created jar.

I might have a classpath issue as I feel from that article, as when I included the `<addClasspath>true</addClasspath>` in the maven plugin, I got some 150+ dependency jar files as Class-Path in my MANIFEST.MF file. These jar files are also in my jar\Boot-INF\lib, whereas my code files are in jar\BOOT-INF\classes. Do you think it has something to do with it and how can I solve this?

My POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.fully.qualified</groupId>
<artifactId>name</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>example</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
    <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <scala.majorVersion>2.11</scala.majorVersion>
    <scala.minorVersion>8</scala.minorVersion>
    <start-class>com.fully.qualified.name.Demo</start-class>
</properties>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>scala-tools.org</id>
        <name>Scala-tools Maven2 Repository</name>
        <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<repositories>
<repository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Central Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>pele.farmbio.uu.se</id>
        <url>http://pele.farmbio.uu.se/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>scala-tools.org</id>
        <name>Scala-tools Maven2 Repository</name>
        <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.majorVersion}.${scala.minorVersion}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.lamma</groupId>
        <artifactId>lamma_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- fix java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.UncheckedCompileException -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.janino</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-compile</id>
                    <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <recompileMode>incremental</recompileMode>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
            <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <mainClass>com.fully.qualified.name.Demo</mainClass>
                </manifest>

            </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>assemble-all</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

<!-- Following is to remove pom errors only -->
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        net.alchim31.maven
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        scala-maven-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [2.15.2,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>compile</goal>
                                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Java command: `java -jar example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

`java -jar example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` works just fine.

Thanks.

Comment: please, include your POM and the command you are using for booting up

Comment: Updated, please have a look.

Comment: did you try with "mvn spring-boot:run" ?

Comment: Yes, it does work, but I can also run it from STS directly. The goal is to deploy it on Azure, and for this I need to have a working jar file. Which is not even working on localhost. Debugging on Azure comes later :-(

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue? I am currently having the same issue with spring boot not running when jarred with dependencies.

Comment: I don't remember exactly how I solved that, but I do remember using an alternative approach. I am sorry that I can't tell you anything more than that.